# Light covering constantly 2 same sides of a rotating cube

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I made a basic lighting for a rotating rainbow cube:

vshader:

```
attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute  vec4 vColor;
attribute  vec4 vNormal;

varying vec4 color;

uniform mat4 ModelView;
uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;
uniform vec4 lPosition;
uniform vec4 lDiffuse;
uniform vec4 Shininess;
uniform vec4 lSpecular;
uniform vec4 lAmbient;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_eye;


void main() 
{

    vec4 ambient, diffuse, specular;
    vec3 N,L,E,H;

    //gl_Position = projection * view * model * vPosition;
    ambient = vColor*lAmbient;

    N = normalize((ModelView*vNormal).xyz);
    L = normalize((ModelView*lPosition).xyz - (ModelView*vPosition).xyz);
    diffuse = max(dot(L,N), 0.0)*(vColor*lDiffuse);

    E = -normalize((ModelView * vPosition).xyz);
    H = normalize(L + E);
    specular = max(pow(max(dot(N, H), 0.0), 20.0)
                *lSpecular, 0.0);

    color = vec4((ambient+diffuse+specular).rgb, 1.0);

    gl_Position = Projection * ModelView * vPosition;
}
```

When the cube is rotating I can see only 2 sides being shaded, rest of them is black. The light is all the time in the same position (front of the cube), but even if the walls being shaded from the beginning are not facing the light source are visible and rest is not. Suggestions?

// edit normals are calculated like this:

void normals(int a, int b, int c, int d) {

```
vec4 U, V;
U = vertices[b] - vertices[a];
V = vertices[c] - vertices[a];

vec4 firstNormal;
firstNormal.x = (U.y * V.z)-(U.z * V.y);
firstNormal.y = (U.z * V.x)-(U.x * V.z);
firstNormal.z = (U.x * V.y)-(U.y * V.x);
firstNormal.w = 1.0f;

normal[normalCount] = firstNormal;
normalCount++;

vec4 X, Y;

X = vertices[c] - vertices[a];
Y = vertices[d] - vertices[a];

vec4 secondNormal;
secondNormal.x = (X.y * Y.z)-(X.z * Y.y);
secondNormal.y = (X.z * Y.x)-(X.x * Y.z);
secondNormal.z = (X.x * Y.y)-(X.y * Y.x);
secondNormal.w = 1.0f;

normal[normalCount] = secondNormal;
normalCount++;
```

}

where they are send to vbo abcd are vertices on corners of a side of he cube

Comment: Where's your `#version` directive?  Fragment shader?

Comment: i was doing it from some examples and now it has version 120. Dont know why from my examples at school we were using #140 and it was working on my macbook pro / now it says it is not suported. Fragment shader just gets the color from vs

Answer (score 0):

1) what are your normals? you can have a bug there, it would show like that. you can check that by assigning and testing, in turns:

```
color = vNormal; 
color = N; 
color = L;
```

and so on.

2) you're using per-vertex, not per-fragment shading, which, on a cube, might not be the best idea - it's too imprecise.